# How can I read the contents of an xlsx file stored on Sharepoint?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, sharepoint

I need to read a sheet called "Input" from the file data.xlsx present in a Sharepoint location.

Code snippet -

```
import openpyxl
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
import errno

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext("something.com/sites/mainLocation/NextLocation/dir?csf=something&web=something&e=something")
print(ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(Username, Password))
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(Username, Password):
  ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

  response = File.open_binary(ctx, "data.xlsx")
  
  df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response.content),sheet_name="Input", header=1, usecols=["c1","c3","c4","c9"],engine='openpyxl')
  
  print(df)
```

Output -

```
Authentication successful
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000024930156E30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\Doc\Store.py", line 42, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response.content),sheet_name="Input",engine='openpyxl')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 478, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1513, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 549, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 540, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 560, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 344, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 95, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1302, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\zipfile.py", line 1369, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I am not allowed to convert the required data to .csv. I have to read the sheet from the xlsx file only, and keep it in pandas dataframe.

I can read the file very well when it is kept in my local folder using -

```
df = pd.read_excel("localpath/data.xlsx",sheet_name="Input", header=1, usecols=["c1","c3","c4","c9"])
```

When reading from SharePoint location, its creating an issue, although authentication is successful.
Please help.

Adding -

As suggested by Abdul, I printed response.status_code. It showed 200. But the error is persisting in the line - df=pd.read_excel(....). Kindly help.

EDIT -

I tried another way but that also did not work. Here is the code

```
site_url="direct link to the file data.xlsx which I found by opening the file in SharePoint, then clicking Share -> Copy Link"

tx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
print(ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(Username, Password))
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(Username, Password):
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, site_url)
    print(response.status_code)
    #save data to BytesIO stream
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start
    #read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
    df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name="Input",header=1, usecols=["c1","c3","c4","c9"], engine='openpyxl')
    print(df.shape)
```

Authentication was successful. Response status was 200. But the same error persisted -

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Please someone kindly advise.

EDIT -

I used xlrd instead of openpyxl -

```
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response.content),sheet_name="Input", header=1, usecols=["c1","c3","c4","c9"],engine='xlrd')
```

Error is as follows -

```
in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'
```

I also tried this -

```
df = pd.read_html(bytes_file_obj
```

Error -

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

Please help.

Edit -

As suggested, I have printed `response.content.decode()`.

Given below is the beginning of the response -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us".....
```

Comment: Did you check `response.status_code`?

Comment: I checked with print(response.status_code). It is printing 200. The df = pd.read_excel(...) line is showing the error.

Comment: What is inside the content? I mean is it really a binary file or some html code?

Comment: I have opened the file data.xlsx in Notepad++. The contents start with PK...after that there are some nonsense symbols...after that its written [Content_Types].xml......after that entire file is full of nonsense symbols that are not human readable. But the file is not corrupted because it works perfect while using ```pd.read_excel()``` when I read from local. Only from Share Point its causing issue. Also I am adding above, the error I got using xlrd instead of openpyxl when reading from Sharepoint.

Comment: I was curious about `response.content`, what's inside of it and what's its size? If everything's alright then I'd expect that `response.content[:4].hex() == '504b0304'` (see [zip-structure docs](https://docs.fileformat.com/compression/zip/)). Also it should be equal in size to the actual file. You obtain either really not zip-file (see the first 4 bites) or not the full file but only some first chunk `os.path.getsize(path_to_local_file) == len(response.content)`.

Comment: ```response.content[:4].hex()``` is coming as ```'0d0a3c21'``` .  ```len(response.content)``` is coming as ```91969```  .  ```os.path.getsize(path_to_local_file)``` is ```163143``` . The file data.xlsx is .xlsx file and not zip file, so is the hex value expected to come as 504b0304? Also, the files are same both in local and in Sharepoint location. Still, I dont understand mismatch between ```len(response.content)``` and the local file size. Is any change needed in the code? I am doing this activity for the first time, so I request to kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: XLSX is a zip package with a bunch of XML files inside (see [1.3 Structure Overview](https://msopenspecs.azureedge.net/files/MS-XLSX/%5bMS-XLSX%5d.pdf) in official docs). As of `response.content`, from what you show it's some html-document which starts with `'\r\n<!'` (and I'd expect `DOCTYPE ...` as the following characters). Look inside of it `print(response.content.decode())`

Comment: I have added the response of ```print(response.content.decode())``` in problem description above. Its starting with ```<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us"....```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [File object](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/0dd6039e0f6aa707a9b3d3042a5b9152bf2ecd9c/office365/sharepoint/files/file.py#L48), it seems that the `get_content` or `download` methods fit better then `open_binary`. The first one returns the `ClientResult` object with the `value` property, where I guess the content is stored. The second seems to write the content in the local file and it uses `get_content` inside to get the data. And `open_binary` seems to be a direct request which returns not the data in some intermediate object but their representation in the html format.

So two alternatives looks reasonable to try. One is to download file locally and then open it:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import environ

site_url = ... 
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_user_credentials(Username, Password)
file_name = 'data.xlsx'
server_relative_path = Path(...) / file_name
download_path = Path(environ['HOME']) / 'Downloads' / file_name
with open(download_path, 'wb') as my_file:
    (
        ctx.web
        .get_file_by_server_relative_path(server_relative_path)
        .download(my_file)
        .execute_query()
    )

df = pd.read_excel(download_path, ...)
```

The other one is to obtain the content this way:

```
site_url = ... 
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_user_credentials(Username, Password)
server_relative_path = ...
file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(server_relative_path)
file_content = file.get_content().execute_query()
# in the line below we may need to use file_content.value instead of file_content
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_content), ...)
```